# In self join why one table giving null value?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I'm using databricks community edition. I created a temporary view.

```
%python
df.createOrReplaceTempView("athlete_events_csv")
```

[image: The table view schema]

The query i'm writing

```
with medal_count_by_country as
(SELECT NOC, Year, count(*) as medal_count, row_number() over( partition by NOC order by Year) as year_count
FROM athlete_events_csv
WHERE Medal in ('Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze')
GROUP BY NOC, Year)

SELECT m1.NOC, m1.Year, m1.medal_count, m1.year_count, m2.year_count, ((m1.medal_count - m2.medal_count)/m1.medal_count)*100 as percentage_increase
FROM medal_count_by_country m1 left join medal_count_by_country m2
ON m1.NOC = m2.NOC AND m1.Year = m2.Year and m1.year_count-1 = m2.year_count
```

[image: The query output]

Can anyone please guide me why the 'm2.year' count is showing as 'Null'?

I've a data-set about country, year etc wise athlete event details. I'm trying to get YOY winners' percentage increase.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like data from the Summer Olympics? They're only held every 4 years, you probably need your join to be `m1.year_count-4 = m2.year_count`

Comment: ok, but it doesn't depend on year, i'm actually indexing it with window function. ```row_number() over( partition by NOC order by Year) ```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in `join` clause is wrong in this case.

The part that causes the issue is `m1.Year = m2.Year`.

You are trying to `join` data frames by *year* and then by `row_number` ordered by the same year column. That is why you get only `null` values. There are nothing to return.

Remove that part and you will receive proper results.